# Proving $f: G \to H$ is injective or surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> If both $G=H=\mathbb Q$ are the set of all rational numbers and $f:G \to H$, when proving injectivity or surjectivity is there any substantial difference in process?

I am familiar with the process of proving the set of integers mapped to the set of integers as being injective and/or surjective, but I am not aware if any major difference is made when the sets are changed from integers to quotients? From my current understanding the process is essentially the same but I cannot find much reliable information to support that consensus? In similar regard would taking the set of real numbers change the process involved?

Comment: Why do you think it would be any different?

Comment: It's the same process.

Comment: do you mean rational numbers by saying quotients…？

Comment: Yes I do mean the rational numbers sorry. Is that the preferred terminology? I had just read a proof in the library that implied (to me at least) that when you have the set of quotients for example you have to take into consideration their form $\frac{a}{b}$ whereas I have sort of them been treating them like integers since it is the set of quotients mapped to the set of quotients?

Comment: I am sort of struggling in this area so I am not sure if I have the appropriate level of knowledge to translate what I am trying to understand here?

Comment: Please refer to them as rational numbers, not set of quotients.

Comment: @James The definitions of surjectivity and injectivity are independent of the specific nature of sets. To be precise, the property of being (injective/surjective) is defined for any "aribitrary" function between any two "arbitrary" sets $A, B$ which are not required to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ be defined by $f(a)=a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Q}$. We wish to show that $f$ is injective and surjective.

For injective, let $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ and assume $f(a)=f(b)$. This means $a=f(a)=f(b)=b$, hence $a=b$, so $f$ is injective.

For surjective, let $a\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f(a)=a$, so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I don't see how this answers OP's question. You have just proven that the identity $\operatorname{id} \colon \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is bijective, which is trivial.

Comment: This is to illustrate that it is the exact same process.